# Web page design view in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm working on a project in PHP using Netbeans IDE which is best for coding part but when I'm coding HTML part if I want to see Design view in Netbeans, that is not visible in Netbeans so is there any plugin or software that can make design view of web page like in Dreamweaver can also show in Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the Dreamweaver view is very inconsistent. Just because it views perfectly in Dreamweaver it does not mean it will render well in a browser, and vise versa.

I would advice you to simply test all your designs within the browser itself. After all, your users will be using the browser to get to the website.

A simple `ctrl`+`s` and an `alt`+`tab` is very fast, assuming you're on windows.

Comment: I'd add that you test all your designs in *multiple* browsers (and even different versions of the same browser).